# How can i limit my update function on Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel

I need to do an update, and I can't get it to work. I want to update my 'TIME' to right now on my last inserted row of 'number'. Everything works, but it saves on every row that matches 'number', and not only the last. This is the only error I'm getting. I have tried everything, and nothing solves my problem. However, I believe it is has a simple solution.

```
public function update()
{
    DB::table('register')
        ->where('number', $this->number)
        ->limit(1)
        ->orderByDesc('id')
        ->update(['time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly limit an `UPDATE` statement, it will run on every record matching your conditions.

In order to achieve what you're trying to do you have to find which record is the latest one and then directly update it.

The easiest way you can do it is with two different queries:

```php
// Get the latest record on the "register" table
$latest = DB::table('register')
  ->where('number', $this->number)
  ->limit(1)
  ->orderByDesc('id')
  ->first(); // <-- Executes the query and returns the first element

// Update it with the current time
if ($latest !== null) { // <-- $latest could be null if the "register" table is empty
  DB::table('register')
    ->where('id', $latest->id)
    ->update(['time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
}
```

Comment: Now im getting the error : 'Call to undefined method stdClass::update()'

Comment: You cannot use `first` and then update on the query. If you remove the first the error will dissapear, but the query will end up doing the same thing that you wrote on your thread. @Master Are you sure that it's updatign more than 1 row ?

Comment: Im absolutely sure. Every single row that matches 'number' are updated

Comment: @Master Can you change the $number into a another static variable rather than your $number? Retry again and check how many rows will be updated

Comment: `DB` does not return a model with DB methods like `update` or `delete` on it; it just returns a `stdClass`. You would need to expand the update to be something like `DB::table(...)->where('id', $latest->id)->update(...)`.

Comment: I should do that inside the 'if' statement @BrianThompson ?

Comment: To make this answer work without an error, yes. But I was mostly addressing the answerer, I don't know if that's the only issue

Comment: Yeah, sorry I couldn't check the code before submitting. @BrianThompson is right and I've updated my answer. Hope it helps, thanks!

Comment: @nickfla1 answer along with Brian Thompson's was the solution to my problem. Working perfectly now. Ty guys so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
        DB::table('register')
            ->where('number',$this->number)
            ->latest('id')
            ->limit(1)
            ->update(['time' => Carbon::now()]);
```

Edit: Latest by default sorts descending by column `created_at`. You can override that and pass the column you wish. ie: latest('id')

Comment: I'll try,but what about my ''where'' for the number? I def need it. The row i'll be updating will NOT be the last inserted row in the DB,but it will be the last inserted row with the specific number value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The error im getting now is 'Call to undefined method stdClass::update()'

Comment: Reupated, just tested in a project of mine and it works. Updates only the last record in my condition. Let me know if it solves your solution

Comment: Laravel's database class will handle the ordering of the limit/orderBy clauses. Doesn't matter what order you call them in.

Comment: @ceejayoz okay that's right. Something i learnt too.. But it means his code is correct at the first place too

Comment: Well,very sadly,it is still not working for me :(.
Keeps on saving on every row completely ignoring the limit()
I must be gething something wrong. This exact same code worked on you project?

Comment: @Master You're sure you don't have a wayward get() in there somewhere?

Comment: Absolutely not one single 'get' in my whole script

Comment: @Master Can you share the whole method ?